# C# Extension methods and protection level?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to write an extension method for the MVC controller class, since I see such code repeatedly in my program:

```
if (viewModel == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
return View(viewModel);
```

The idea is that I want an extension method called `ViewModelResult()` to take care of this, so that it will return either an `ActionResult` or `HttpNotFound` result depending on whether the view model is available. This way, I dont have to write these 3-4 lines of code every time.

However, it seems that the protection level of the methods `View()` and `HttpNotFound()` in the MVC controller is causing some serious trouble. I've written the code as below but it will not work:

```
public static class ExtensionController
{
    public static ActionResult ViewModelResult(this Controller controller, ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (viewModel == null)
        {
            return controller.HttpNotFound();
        }
        return controller.View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

It throws error messages such as "System.Web.MVC.Controller.View() is inaccessible due to its protection level". This confuses me, I thought in extension methods all private and protected methods of the very object labeled by `this` keyword are accessible, just like when you write a method in this class. But I've been proved wrong, those non-public methods are inaccessible in extension methods.

Now the question is, how can I get by this issue? I am kinda clueless, don't know what I can do about this. The MVC controller class comes within the .NET framework, and I cannot modify the source code. It is not recommended to change internal implementation of .NET framework anyway. Can anyone help? What do you recommend me to do in this case?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a subclass of the `Controller` class and add methods to that.

```
public abstract class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected ActionResult ViewModelResult(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (viewModel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}

public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var vm = ...;
        return ViewModelResult(vm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to complete the answer of @Markus:
You can access the View method only by inheritance as you can see on the MSDN [Controller.View Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460331(v=vs.118).aspx)

Extension methods are purely syntactic sugar and are replaced at compile time by your `ExtensionController.ViewModelResult(this,viewModel);`

Hence you can access only public modifiers if your extension class is not part of the library of the object you want to extend.